# ¿Puedo hacer que un formulario sea enviado al escuchar un onChange en ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy creando una notificación por correo sirviéndome de la librería email.js, el asunto es que necesito que sin necesidad de hacer click sobre un botón, se ejecute la función de envío del correo. He intentado con un onChange que al escuchar un cambio dentro de un input ejecute la función, sin embargo, no pasa nada.

Esta es la función que está enviando el correo.

```
const sendEmail = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    emailjs.sendForm('service_146u8tf', 'template_r74u0pu', event.target, 'c3Gkm9- 
    Nf0vJFCRKY')
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
  }
```

Este es el formulario o parte de él:

```
<form onSubmit={sendEmail}  >
        <div  >
          <input type="text" name='user_name' value={userLogged.name}/>
          <input type="text" name='user_email' value={userLogged.email}/>
          <input type="text" name='user_message' value={'Tienes un nuevo mensaje sin leer'}/>
          <input type="text" name='user_reply' value={user.email} />
          <input type="text" value={emailBoolean} onChange={prueba} />
          <button type='submit' className='btnEmail' > <Email/> </button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Saludos!

Comment: `<input type="text" value={emailBoolean} onChange={prueba} />` en tu evento change estas usando una funcion llamada prueba, pero arriba en tu codigo la funcion tiene otro nombre...`sendEmail()`

Comment: Ademas enviar un email  por cada  evento `onchangue` va a realizar un envio masivo de correos electronicos (spam).

Comment: Creo que hace falta una mejor explicación, si lo que desea es enviar el formulario cuando todos los datos del formulario sean llenados es posible con un evento onChange en cada input del form que valide si ningún dato es vacío, el problema aqui es que en cuanto se llene el ultimo input se hara la petición automatica y no dejara llenar de información el ultimo input, esto es posible solucionarse con un debouser, pero es ineficiente la mejor solución es un boton, ahora si el formulario no tendra cambios se puede hacer de alguna otra manera, pero se necesita mas información.